# Gif image is not showing up in Twitter Bootstrap modal box in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put gif image( loader ) in Twitter Bootstrap modal box.It is showing up in Firefox but not in  Google Chrome. Please help me out 
Here is my HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide holiday_box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 50%;width: 580px;height: 170px;margin: -85px 0px 0px -290px;padding: 20px;">
```

And CSS

```
<div style='display:block;margin:25px auto;width:188px;height:60px;background-image: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);'></div>
```

Comment: Use the Chrome developer tool to inspect why the image isn't loading.  You haven't provided enough detail in your question to make any direct suggestions.  The amount of variables that can affect an image displaying is too high to guess.  If you upload a full working example, we can give you an accurate recommendation for a fix.

Comment: thanks for reply @Axel, here is the link https://travel-logs.in/portal/traveliq/travel_img after dragging 6 images on right handside box after clicking on 'I have made my choices',comes bootstrap modal box on this modal there is a gif loader which I can see in Firefox but it is not visible in Chrome.Please check if you can help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: Try including it in your CSS as a class, and applying the class to that div.  I think the inline styles you are using aren't being rendered because of the way you are loading them into the page.  Also, you might want to focus on the usability of your drag & drop feature.  I literally had to drag and drop items over and over again to get them to stick.

Comment: thanks @Axel will try this,On the drag and drop point I am working on it to make it smother.